# MySQL get recent Updates and Inserts

Tags: mysql

I've MySQL 5.7. There are some recent update statements ran in MySQL and I have to see what update statement did they run. I tried the `mysqlbinlog <bin-log>` but it give lots of output which I'm not able to trace the recent ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a -v in your command:

`mysqlbinlog -v <bin-log>`

Comment: Yeah I think that's a very good parameter. Thank you so much @JamieCropley